# AutoFixure Fixture.Build().With() with different values

Tags: c#, autofixture

Consider a class

```
class A
{
    public class NestedA
    {
        public string StrWithInt { get; set; }

        public string Str1 { get; set; }

        public string Str2 { get; set; }
    }

    public List<NestedA> Items { get; set; }
}
```

I am using [AutoFixture](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture) framework for generating instances of class `A` with random contents. 
The `NestedA`'s class property `StrWithInt` is a `string` type but its value has to be a number, int value. So I am using a [With()](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/wiki/Cheat-Sheet#set-property) method to customize generation.

My code looks like below:

```
Random r = new Random();
Fixture fixture = new Fixture();
fixture.Customize<A.NestedA>(ob =>
    ob.With(p => p.StrWithInt, r.Next().ToString())
);
var sut = fixture.Build<A>().Create();

foreach (var it in sut.Items)
{
   Console.WriteLine($"StrWithInt: {it.StrWithInt}");
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

I get a such result.

> StrWithInt: 340189285 
>   StrWithInt: 340189285 
>   StrWithInt: 340189285

All values are same. But I am expected to see different values of this property. 
How Can I reach it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `With(...)` method has many overloads among which you can find the  following:

```
IPostprocessComposer<T> With<TProperty>(
      Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> propertyPicker,
      Func<TProperty> valueFactory);
```

So you can use this one via passing factory of random numbers and after this result always will be different:

```
fixture.Customize<A.NestedA>(ob =>
    ob.With(p => p.StrWithInt, () => r.Next().ToString())
);
```

In your case you choose the static one which always assign the same value to the specified property.

Comment: Thanks Nikita. It turned out to be much easier than I thought.